# Problem: Tikz \shadedraw and backward search

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with forward/backward search in tex. I'm using Miktex, Texniccenter and SumatraPDF and normally the search works just fine. I tried to make a minimal example.

I use one main file (main.tex), where I load my packages, define new commands, etc. and load my single chapter files (1.tex, 2.tex, 3.tex) via \include{}. In some of these files I use tikz-pictures, which are stored in separate tex-files and loaded via \input{*.tex}.

Here is the example:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\include{1}
\include{2}
\include{3}

\end{document}
```

1.tex:

```
Test 1.1
\input{pic.tex}
Test 1.2
```

2.tex:

```
Test 2
```

3.tex:

```
Test 3
```

pic.tex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shadedraw[top color=yellow,bottom color=black] (0,0) rectangle +(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The document compiles just fine and looks the way it is supposed to. But if I try the backward search (clicking in the pdf => jumping to the right line in the tex-file), it does not work for the "Test 2" part (of file 2.tex). I get the error: "no synchronisation info at this point" in SumatraPDF. If I click on "Test 1.1" or "Test 1.2", it directs me to "pic.tex", for whatever reason. Only the backward search used at "Test 3" and the picture itself work correctly.

If I use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[yellow] (0,0) rectangle +(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

as pic.tex the backward search works just fine.

Any ideas why there is a problem with \shadedraw?

If you need more information, please let me know.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
\shadedraw[top color=yellow,bottom color=black,draw=yellow] (0,0) rectangle +(2,1);
```

or

```
\shade[top color=yellow,bottom color=black] (0,0) rectangle +(2,1);
```

It seems if you use `shadedraw` you must specify a colour for the border. For no border `shade` is more appropriate.

Comment: Did you try the backward search with SumatraPDF and with your solution?

Comment: if the color is not given the default `black` is assumed but how is that relevant to the backward search?